# Lua replace quotes after decoding

Tags: string, lua

How would I attempt this?

I'm trying to create something that would remove all quotes (`" "`) in a Lua file but I have had no luck so far. But it might be because im a newbie at Lua.

I'm using this from GitHub.

```
function from_base64(to_decode)
    local padded = to_decode:gsub("%s", "")
    local unpadded = padded:gsub("=", "")
    local bit_pattern = ''
    local decoded = ''

    for i = 1, string.len(unpadded) do
        local char = string.sub(to_decode, i, i)
        local offset, _ = string.find(index_table, char)
        if offset == nil then
             error("Invalid character '" .. char .. "' found.")
        end

        bit_pattern = bit_pattern .. string.sub(to_binary(offset-1), 3)
    end

    for i = 1, string.len(bit_pattern), 8 do
        local byte = string.sub(bit_pattern, i, i+7)
        decoded = decoded .. string.char(from_binary(byte))
    end

    local padding_length = padded:len()-unpadded:len()

    if (padding_length == 1 or padding_length == 2) then
        decoded = decoded:sub(1,-2)
    end
    return decoded
end
```

Comment: How are you loading the file's contents? What have you tried at this point?

Comment: Well im not sure about your question but after i decode the text it leaves it as a string (which i dont want). Ive tried string.gsub("""", " ")

Comment: How are you getting the string from the file? What do you think `""""` (four double quotes) is being seen as by lua? Try `print("""")` and see.

Comment: (Not mine but i have tried modifying it but i have failed)

Comment: So you are loading a base64 encoded string from a file (somehow) then running that to decode it and ending up with a string with double quotes in it that you would like to remove? `gsub` is the right answer you just aren't passing the first argument correctly. See what `print("""")` outputs. Is it what you expect the first argument to `gsub` to be?

Comment: Ive got the base64 down but no im not ending up with double quotes. Im ending up with the whole code being quoted one at the start and an end quote at the end of the file.

Comment: Hm? How are you printing the decoded string? Can you show an truncated/etc. example of what you are ending up with?

Comment: Im ending up with all my code being printed. Im using PrintChat(Videogame stuff)

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to create something that would remove all quotes (" ") in a Lua file

```
-- read contents of file into memory
local file = io.open(filename)
local text = file:read('*a')
file:close()

-- remove all double-quotes from the contents
text = text:gsub('"','')

-- write contents back to the file
local file = io.open(filename, 'w+')
local text = file:write(text)
file:close()
```